# django aggregation and filtering result

Tags: python, mysql, django, filtering

in Django after aggregation.
if I use `filter` on a column that is not aggregated,
I get it used in the `where` clause of the SQL query
and not in `having` as expected.

### example follows:

I have a table for test results.
Let's say I have TestA and TestB.

```
Version:   2    |   2   |   2
TestA   :Pass   |Null   |Fail
testB   :Error  |Fail   |Null
```

Each test can be run at any time, 

I want to display the latest result for that test.

what I've tried

```
x=Site.results.filter(timeEnd__isnull=False).values('idTest').annotate(Max('timeEnd'))
```

and then filtering x using:

```
x.filter(result=<number of result>)
```

but I get results using the second filter that are not seen in original x.

How can I get the desired result?

but if I try to display:

```
result(Version=2).failedFilter()
TestA=Fail
TestB=Fail

result(Version=2).PassedFilter()
TestA=Pass

result(Version=2).ErrorFilter()
TestB=Error

result(version=2)
TestA=Fail
TestB=Fail
```

when actually besides the Failed Filter all the rest needs to be empty.

**summary:**

```
tables:
test
----
    id
    name

Site
----
    id
    name

testresult
----------
    id
    date
    testid
    siteid
    result(int)
```

**I want to get last result for a site with each test
and then filter it by result.**

Comment: Your table does not make sense. What is self.results? Show us your models.py so we have some idea what's going on

Comment: @airstrike , it's part of the object, self is Site

Answer (score 1):

[latest()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest%20latest%28%29) will return the most recent model in a queryset.

```
site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
for test in Test.objects.all():
        test_result = TestResult.objects.filter(site=site, test=test).latest('timeEnd')
        print test_result.result
```

annotate() just calculates a value, it does not do any filtering. I think your current query will return any tests that have timeEnd set, rather than just the last one (which is what I think you want).

Comment: I want to collect all of the test_result iteration and filter them, and another thing, i've got over 100K tests